# No Compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: java, maven

Before I start, let me tell you that I've been Googling for about an hour or two now, so please don't respond to this question saying "Hey! You know that there's plenty of answers on Google?"

Now to the question: whenever I run `mvn clean package`, I get the this error `No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?`. I've checked my Java versions, and these are the outputs.

**Java JRE**

`java -version` returned `java version "1.8.0_181"`

**Java JDK**

`javac -version` returned `javac 1.8.0_181`

**Maven version**

`mvn -version` returned

```
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T20:33:14+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

From what I found on Google, there should be a line saying `Java Home` or something followed by the JDK version and it's path. As you can see, It's not appearing here. I've tried setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable multiple times, and I verified that it works, by executing `echo %JAVA_HOME`, which returned it's proper path.

Any help?

***EDIT***
Output of `echo %JAVA_HOME%`: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

System variables:

[image]

Comment: What is the proper path? `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181`?

Comment: Please add the output of `echo %JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Edited the original post.

Comment: @XaafCode Also check if `PATH` environment variable has `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` part.

Comment: It does have that.

Comment: @XaafCode, do you run `mvn clean package` in the command line? Not in the IDE (eclipse or Idea)?

Comment: Yes, I run it from Git Bash.

Comment: @XaafCode, try to run it not from GitBash, but from Command line (cmd).

Comment: I tried running it from GitBash and it works. However, make sure that the path is correct? Also do you use any plugins in your pom.xml?

Comment: Trying right now. That seemed to work! Is there a way to get this working with Bash too?

Comment: I do not know. It looks like it is working in my git bash. However, it may be that you have a different version. Also, I do not use any maven plugins. Also, git bash has some tricks, like `set java_home` does not show anything, while in the command line it works.

Comment: Oh well. I'll have to do with CMD for now then. Thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `JDK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` environment variables set?
As @Chris311 says in his comment  `echo %JAVA_HOME` or set in Windows will show if the environment variables was set and set correctly.

```
set JAVA_HOME
```

And yes, `JAVA_HOME` should point to **JDK**, not a *JRE*. For example, for my Windows Machine, it is `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`.

[image]

**Update**

As we figured out, it did not work in the git bash console, but it worked in the command line. I tested `mvn clean package` myself, it seemed to be working. However, some commands that work in cmd do not work in git bash, for example `set java_home` or cd to a path with `\` (I needed to use `/`).

Comment: No? I haven't seen those anywhere else. I'll set them, and then check again.

Comment: Do not use `MAVEN_HOME` cause it is not needed nor used somewhere...only the entry into the `PATH` with the `bin` directory of the Maven installation...

Comment: Yes, I add into the PATH variable `;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: I have the `bin` directory in my Path variable.

Comment: I have `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` set to *exactly* those values, as the installation directories are the same as yours. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue('mvn clean install' was working on the cmd, but not in the Git Bash) and it was resolved by removing the following from the path variable in Environment variables

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"
```